# Combination of task and employee shift scheduling

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I'm trying to solve the following scheduling problem:

- Each day of the week has shifts that can be classified by a primary shift and a secondary shift. These must be performed in parallel;
- Primary shifts have 4 values: off_shift, day, night, availability;
- Secondary shifts have 5 values: task-1, task-2, ..., task-5;
- Workers have different capabilities for both primary and secondary shifts, e.g. Worker-1 can perform all primary-shifts but only task-1 and task-2 of secondary shifts;

I managed to solve the primary shift scheduling, given workers' skills and other constraints by enhancing the nurse shift scheduling example, but I cannot understand how to define the secondary shifts.

Working code:

```
import enum
import itertools
from typing import Tuple, List, Dict, Set, Iterable, Optional

from ortools.sat.python import cp_model


def negated_bounded_span(works, start, length):
    """Filters an isolated sub-sequence of variables assined to True.

  Extract the span of Boolean variables [start, start + length), negate them,
  and if there is variables to the left/right of this span, surround the span by
  them in non negated form.

  Args:
    works: a list of variables to extract the span from.
    start: the start to the span.
    length: the length of the span.

  Returns:
    a list of variables which conjunction will be false if the sub-list is
    assigned to True, and correctly bounded by variables assigned to False,
    or by the start or end of works.
  """
    sequence = []
    # Left border (start of works, or works[start - 1])
    if start > 0:
        sequence.append(works[start - 1])
    for i in range(length):
        sequence.append(works[start + i].Not())
    # Right border (end of works or works[start + length])
    if start + length < len(works):
        sequence.append(works[start + length])
    return sequence


def add_soft_sequence_constraint(model, works, hard_min, soft_min, min_cost,
                                 soft_max, hard_max, max_cost, prefix):
    """Sequence constraint on true variables with soft and hard bounds.

  This constraint look at every maximal contiguous sequence of variables
  assigned to true. If forbids sequence of length < hard_min or > hard_max.
  Then it creates penalty terms if the length is < soft_min or > soft_max.

  Args:
    model: the sequence constraint is built on this model.
    works: a list of Boolean variables.
    hard_min: any sequence of true variables must have a length of at least
      hard_min.
    soft_min: any sequence should have a length of at least soft_min, or a
      linear penalty on the delta will be added to the objective.
    min_cost: the coefficient of the linear penalty if the length is less than
      soft_min.
    soft_max: any sequence should have a length of at most soft_max, or a linear
      penalty on the delta will be added to the objective.
    hard_max: any sequence of true variables must have a length of at most
      hard_max.
    max_cost: the coefficient of the linear penalty if the length is more than
      soft_max.
    prefix: a base name for penalty literals.

  Returns:
    a tuple (variables_list, coefficient_list) containing the different
    penalties created by the sequence constraint.
  """
    cost_literals = []
    cost_coefficients = []

    # Forbid sequences that are too short.
    for length in range(1, hard_min):
        for start in range(len(works) - length + 1):
            model.AddBoolOr(negated_bounded_span(works, start, length))

    # Penalize sequences that are below the soft limit.
    if min_cost > 0:
        for length in range(hard_min, soft_min):
            for start in range(len(works) - length + 1):
                span = negated_bounded_span(works, start, length)
                name = ': under_span(start=%i, length=%i)' % (start, length)
                lit = model.NewBoolVar(prefix + name)
                span.append(lit)
                model.AddBoolOr(span)
                cost_literals.append(lit)
                # We filter exactly the sequence with a short length.
                # The penalty is proportional to the delta with soft_min.
                cost_coefficients.append(min_cost * (soft_min - length))

    # Penalize sequences that are above the soft limit.
    if max_cost > 0:
        for length in range(soft_max + 1, hard_max + 1):
            for start in range(len(works) - length + 1):
                span = negated_bounded_span(works, start, length)
                name = ': over_span(start=%i, length=%i)' % (start, length)
                lit = model.NewBoolVar(prefix + name)
                span.append(lit)
                model.AddBoolOr(span)
                cost_literals.append(lit)
                # Cost paid is max_cost * excess length.
                cost_coefficients.append(max_cost * (length - soft_max))

    # Just forbid any sequence of true variables with length hard_max + 1
    for start in range(len(works) - hard_max):
        model.AddBoolOr(
            [works[i].Not() for i in range(start, start + hard_max + 1)])
    return cost_literals, cost_coefficients


def add_soft_sum_constraint(model, works, hard_min, soft_min, min_cost,
                            soft_max, hard_max, max_cost, prefix):
    """Sum constraint with soft and hard bounds.

  This constraint counts the variables assigned to true from works.
  If forbids sum < hard_min or > hard_max.
  Then it creates penalty terms if the sum is < soft_min or > soft_max.

  Args:
    model: the sequence constraint is built on this model.
    works: a list of Boolean variables.
    hard_min: any sequence of true variables must have a sum of at least
      hard_min.
    soft_min: any sequence should have a sum of at least soft_min, or a linear
      penalty on the delta will be added to the objective.
    min_cost: the coefficient of the linear penalty if the sum is less than
      soft_min.
    soft_max: any sequence should have a sum of at most soft_max, or a linear
      penalty on the delta will be added to the objective.
    hard_max: any sequence of true variables must have a sum of at most
      hard_max.
    max_cost: the coefficient of the linear penalty if the sum is more than
      soft_max.
    prefix: a base name for penalty variables.

  Returns:
    a tuple (variables_list, coefficient_list) containing the different
    penalties created by the sequence constraint.
  """
    cost_variables = []
    cost_coefficients = []
    sum_var = model.NewIntVar(hard_min, hard_max, '')
    # This adds the hard constraints on the sum.
    model.Add(sum_var == sum(works))

    # Penalize sums below the soft_min target.
    if soft_min > hard_min and min_cost > 0:
        delta = model.NewIntVar(-len(works), len(works), '')
        model.Add(delta == soft_min - sum_var)
        # TODO(user): Compare efficiency with only excess >= soft_min - sum_var.
        excess = model.NewIntVar(0, 7, prefix + ': under_sum')
        model.AddMaxEquality(excess, [delta, 0])
        cost_variables.append(excess)
        cost_coefficients.append(min_cost)

    # Penalize sums above the soft_max target.
    if soft_max < hard_max and max_cost > 0:
        delta = model.NewIntVar(-7, 7, '')
        model.Add(delta == sum_var - soft_max)
        excess = model.NewIntVar(0, 7, prefix + ': over_sum')
        model.AddMaxEquality(excess, [delta, 0])
        cost_variables.append(excess)
        cost_coefficients.append(max_cost)

    return cost_variables, cost_coefficients


class ShiftsEnum(enum.IntEnum):
    OFF_SHIFT = 0
    DAY_WATCH = 1
    NIGHTWATCH = 2
    WARD_WATCH = 3


class SecondaryShiftsEnum(enum.IntEnum):
    OFF_SHIFT = 0
    ECO = 1
    CLINIC = 2
    MANO = 3
    EGDS = 4


class Request:
    def __init__(self, shift: ShiftsEnum, day_of_the_month: int):
        self.shift = shift
        self.day_of_the_month = day_of_the_month
        self.penalty = -2

    def get_request(self) -> Tuple[int, int, int]:
        return self.shift.value, self.day_of_the_month, self.penalty


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id_: int,
                 name: str, surname: str,
                 shifts_capabilities: Iterable[ShiftsEnum] = (ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT,
                                                              ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH,
                                                              ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH),
                 secondary_shift_capabilities: Optional[Iterable[SecondaryShiftsEnum]] = None):
        self.id = id_

        self._name = name
        self._surname = surname

        self.requests: List[Request] = []
        if not all(s in ShiftsEnum for s in shifts_capabilities):
            raise ValueError(f"Bad shift capabilities for empoloyee {surname} {name}!")
        self._shifts = shifts_capabilities

        if secondary_shift_capabilities and not all(s in SecondaryShiftsEnum for s in secondary_shift_capabilities):
            raise ValueError(f"Bad secondary shift capabilities for empoloyee {surname} {name}!")
        self.secondary_shift_capabilities = secondary_shift_capabilities

    @property
    def name(self):
        return f"{self._surname} {self._name}"

    @property
    def shifts(self):
        return self._shifts

    def add_request(self, request: Request):
        self.requests.append(request)

    def get_requests(self) -> Tuple[int, int, int, int]:
        return [(self.id,) + req.get_request() for req in self.requests][0]

    def request_vacations(self, from_day: int, to_day: int):
        for day in range(from_day, to_day + 1):
            self.requests.append(Request(ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT, day))


class ShiftConstraint:
    def __init__(self, shift: ShiftsEnum, hard_min: int, soft_min: int, min_penalty: int, soft_max: int, hard_max: int,
                 max_penalty: int):
        self.shift = shift
        self.hard_min = hard_min
        self.soft_min = soft_min
        self.min_penalty = min_penalty
        self.soft_max = soft_max
        self.hard_max = hard_max
        self.max_penalty = max_penalty

    def get_constrain(self) -> Tuple[int, int, int, int, int, int, int]:
        """Return (shift, hard_min, soft_min, min_penalty, soft_max, hard_max, max_penalty)"""
        return self.shift.value, self.hard_min, self.soft_min, self.min_penalty, self.soft_max, self.hard_max, \
               self.max_penalty


class ShiftTransitionConstrain:
    def __init__(self, previous_shift: ShiftsEnum, next_shift: ShiftsEnum, penalty: int):
        """
        :param previous_shift:
        :param next_shift:
        :param penalty: (0 means forbid)
        """
        self.previous_shift = previous_shift
        self.next_shift = next_shift
        self.penalty = penalty

    def get_constrain(self) -> Tuple[int, int, int]:
        return self.previous_shift.value, self.next_shift, self.penalty


class ShiftDay:
    def __init__(self, day, secondary_shifts: Optional[Iterable[SecondaryShiftsEnum]] = None):
        self.day = day
        self.primary_shifts = (ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH, ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH, ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH)
        self.secondary_shifts = secondary_shifts if secondary_shifts else (SecondaryShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT,)


class Simulation:
    def __init__(self, employees: Dict[int, Employee]):
        self.employees = employees
        self._work = {}
        self._model = cp_model.CpModel()
        self._shifts = list(ShiftsEnum)

        num_weeks = 4
        num_days = num_weeks * 7

        for e, empolyee in self.employees.items():
            for s, shift in enumerate(self._shifts):
                for day in range(num_days):
                    self._work[e, s, day] = self._model.NewBoolVar('shift_%s_%s_%i' % (empolyee.name, shift, day))

        # Linear terms of the objective in a minimization context.
        obj_int_vars = []
        obj_int_coeffs = []
        obj_bool_vars = []
        obj_bool_coeffs = []

        # Exactly one shift per day.
        for e in self.employees.keys():
            for d in range(num_days):
                self._model.AddExactlyOne(self._work[e, s, d] for s in range(len(self._shifts)))

        # Employee requests
        requests = itertools.chain([emp.get_requests() for emp in self.employees.values() if emp.requests])
        for e, s, d, w in requests:
            obj_bool_vars.append(self._work[e, s, d])
            obj_bool_coeffs.append(w)

        # Employee capabilities, add constraint for the shifts one cannot perform.
        for i, emp in self.employees.items():
            for d in range(num_days):
                for shift in set(ShiftsEnum) - set(emp.shifts):
                    self._model.Add(self._work[i, shift.value, d] == 0)

        # Weekly sum constraints
        weekly_sum_constraints = {"max_two_nights_per_week": max_two_nights_per_week.get_constrain()}
        for label, ct in weekly_sum_constraints.items():
            shift, hard_min, soft_min, min_cost, soft_max, hard_max, max_cost = ct
            for e in range(len(self.employees)):
                for w in range(num_weeks):
                    works = [self._work[e, shift, d + w * 7] for d in range(7)]
                    variables, coeffs = add_soft_sum_constraint(
                        self._model, works, hard_min, soft_min, min_cost, soft_max,
                        hard_max, max_cost,
                        'weekly_sum_constraint-%s(employee %i, shift %i)' %
                        (label, e, shift))
                    obj_int_vars.extend(variables)
                    obj_int_coeffs.extend(coeffs)

        # Monthly constraints
        monthly_sum_constraints = {"ward_week_wise_shift": ward_week_wise_shift.get_constrain()}
        for label, ct in monthly_sum_constraints.items():
            shift, hard_min, soft_min, min_cost, soft_max, hard_max, max_cost = ct
            for e in range(len(self.employees)):
                works = [self._work[e, shift, d + w * 7] for w in range(num_weeks) for d in range(7)]
                variables, coeffs = add_soft_sum_constraint(
                    self._model, works, hard_min, soft_min, min_cost, soft_max,
                    hard_max, max_cost,
                    'monthly_sum_constraints-%s(employee %i, shift %i)' %
                    (label, e, shift))
                obj_int_vars.extend(variables)
                obj_int_coeffs.extend(coeffs)

        # Penalized transitions
        penalized_transitions = {k: constr.get_constrain() for k, constr in
                                 {"forbid_night_to_ward_constrain": forbid_night_to_ward_constrain,
                                  "forbid_night_to_day_watch_constrain": forbid_night_to_day_watch_constrain,
                                  "forbid_night_after_ward_constrain": forbid_night_after_ward_constrain,
                                  "forbid_day_watch_after_ward_constrain": forbid_day_watch_after_ward_constrain,
                                  "penalty_for_ward": penalty_for_ward
                                  }.items()}
        for label, (previous_shift, next_shift, cost) in penalized_transitions.items():
            for e in range(len(self.employees)):
                for d in range(num_days - 1):
                    transition = [
                        self._work[e, previous_shift, d].Not(),
                        self._work[e, next_shift, d + 1].Not()
                    ]
                    if cost == 0:
                        self._model.AddBoolOr(transition)
                    else:
                        trans_var = self._model.NewBoolVar(
                            'transition-%s (employee=%i, day=%i)' % (label, e, d))
                        transition.append(trans_var)
                        self._model.AddBoolOr(transition)
                        obj_bool_vars.append(trans_var)
                        obj_bool_coeffs.append(cost)

        # Cover constraints
        excess_cover_penalties = list({ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT: 2,
                                       ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH: 2,
                                       ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH: 5,
                                       ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH: 0
                                       }.values())

        for s in range(1, len(self._shifts)):
            for w in range(num_weeks):
                for d in range(7):
                    works = [self._work[e, s, w * 7 + d] for e in range(len(self.employees))]
                    # Ignore Off shift.
                    required = 1
                    worked = self._model.NewIntVar(required, len(self.employees), '')
                    self._model.Add(worked == sum(works))
                    over_penalty = excess_cover_penalties[s - 1]
                    if over_penalty > 0:
                        name = 'excess_demand(shift=%i, week=%i, day=%i)' % (s, w,
                                                                             d)
                        excess = self._model.NewIntVar(0, len(self.employees) - required,
                                                       name)
                        self._model.Add(excess == worked - required)
                        obj_int_vars.append(excess)
                        obj_int_coeffs.append(over_penalty)

        # Objective
        self._model.Minimize(
            sum(obj_bool_vars[i] * obj_bool_coeffs[i]
                for i in range(len(obj_bool_vars))) +
            sum(obj_int_vars[i] * obj_int_coeffs[i]
                for i in range(len(obj_int_vars))))

        # Solve the model.
        solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
        solution_printer = cp_model.ObjectiveSolutionPrinter()
        status = solver.Solve(self._model, solution_printer)

        self.print_solution(num_days, num_weeks, obj_bool_coeffs, obj_bool_vars,
                            obj_int_coeffs, obj_int_vars, solver, status)

    def print_solution(self, num_days, num_weeks, obj_bool_coeffs, obj_bool_vars,
                       obj_int_coeffs, obj_int_vars, solver, status):
        if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
            print()
            header = '          '
            cell_size = len(max(i.name for i in ShiftsEnum))
            for w in range(num_weeks):
                header += 'M T W T F S S '.replace(" ", " " * cell_size)
            print(header)
            shifts = list(ShiftsEnum)
            for e, emp in self.employees.items():
                schedule = ''
                for d in range(num_days):
                    for s in range(len(self._shifts)):
                        if solver.BooleanValue(self._work[e, s, d]):
                            schedule += f"{shifts[s].name:11}"
                print(f'Worker %s:\t%s' % (emp.name, schedule))
            print()
            print('Penalties:')
            for i, var in enumerate(obj_bool_vars):
                if solver.BooleanValue(var):
                    penalty = obj_bool_coeffs[i]
                    if penalty > 0:
                        print('  %s violated, penalty=%i' % (var.Name(), penalty))
                    else:
                        print('  %s fulfilled, gain=%i' % (var.Name(), -penalty))

            for i, var in enumerate(obj_int_vars):
                if solver.Value(var) > 0:
                    print('  %s violated by %i, linear penalty=%i' %
                          (var.Name(), solver.Value(var), obj_int_coeffs[i]))
        print()
        print('Statistics')
        print('  - status          : %s' % solver.StatusName(status))
        print('  - conflicts       : %i' % solver.NumConflicts())
        print('  - branches        : %i' % solver.NumBranches())
        print('  - wall time       : %f s' % solver.WallTime())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # forbidden constrains
    forbid_night_to_day_watch_constrain = ShiftTransitionConstrain(ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH, ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH, 0)
    forbid_night_to_ward_constrain = ShiftTransitionConstrain(ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH, ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH, 0)
    forbid_night_after_ward_constrain = ShiftTransitionConstrain(ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH, ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH, 0)
    forbid_day_watch_after_ward_constrain = ShiftTransitionConstrain(ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH, ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH, 0)

    # penalties
    penalty_for_ward = ShiftTransitionConstrain(ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH, ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT, 1)

    # weekly sum constraints on shift days:
    max_two_nights_per_week = ShiftConstraint(ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 100)
    ward_week_wise_shift = ShiftConstraint(ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 1)

    # Optimizations
    penalty_for_more_than_two_consecutive_weekends = None

    weekly_cover_demands = [
        ShiftDay(0, (SecondaryShiftsEnum.MANO,)),
        ShiftDay(1,
                 (SecondaryShiftsEnum.CLINIC, SecondaryShiftsEnum.ECO, SecondaryShiftsEnum.MANO,
                  SecondaryShiftsEnum.EGDS)),
        ShiftDay(2, (SecondaryShiftsEnum.MANO, SecondaryShiftsEnum.CLINIC)),
        ShiftDay(3),
        ShiftDay(4, (SecondaryShiftsEnum.CLINIC,)),
        ShiftDay(5),
        ShiftDay(6)
    ]

    employees = {0: Employee(0, "", "B", (ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT,
                                          ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH),
                             (SecondaryShiftsEnum.ECO, SecondaryShiftsEnum.CLINIC,)),
                 1: Employee(1, "", "S", (ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT,
                                          ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH), (
                                 SecondaryShiftsEnum.EGDS,
                                 SecondaryShiftsEnum.CLINIC,
                                 SecondaryShiftsEnum.MANO
                             )),
                 2: Employee(2, "", "A", (ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT,
                                          ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH), (
                                 SecondaryShiftsEnum.CLINIC,
                                 SecondaryShiftsEnum.MANO
                             )),
                 3: Employee(3, "", "F", (ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT, ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH,)),
                 4: Employee(4, "", "P", (ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT, ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH,)),
                 5: Employee(5, "", "As", (ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT,
                                           ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH,
                                           ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH,
                                           )),
                 6: Employee(6, "", "R", (ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT,
                                          ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH), (
                                 SecondaryShiftsEnum.CLINIC,
                                 SecondaryShiftsEnum.MANO
                             )),
                 7: Employee(7, "", "M", (ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT,
                                          ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH), (

                                 SecondaryShiftsEnum.CLINIC,
                                 SecondaryShiftsEnum.EGDS
                             )),
                 8: Employee(8, "", "L", (ShiftsEnum.OFF_SHIFT,
                                          ShiftsEnum.DAY_WATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH,
                                          ShiftsEnum.WARD_WATCH),
                             (SecondaryShiftsEnum.CLINIC, SecondaryShiftsEnum.EGDS
                              ))
                 }

    employees[2].add_request(Request(ShiftsEnum.NIGHTWATCH, 5))
    employees[4].request_vacations(12, 19)

    sim = Simulation(employees)
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: You should checkout prolog  it is literally designed for this kind of problem

Comment: Code added, it still a toy to experiment, but it has it all. To this I need to add the secondary shift assignement, but I cannot understand how to do it. I tried to add another key to self._work[e, s, s2, day], but without luck.

Comment: can one person performs a primary and a secondary shift at the same time ?

Comment: Yes they must perform both

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this by adding another variable for the secondary task (e.g. `self._secondary_work`) and requesting the solver both must be fulfilled by the conditions.

So practically one must just another `self._work` dictionary and add all required constraints. One can also add constraints taking into account variables from both dictionaries (e.g. mutual exclusion between `self._work` and `self._secondary_work`).